# Why I can't inherit map in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I want to write a self defined class that inherit map class.

```
class MapT(map):
    def __init__(self, iii):
        self.obj = iii
```

But I can't initialize it.

```
# Example init object
ex = map(None,["","1","2"])

exp1 = MapT(ex)
# TypeError: map() must have at least two arguments.

exp1 = MapT(None,ex)
# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

How do I create a class that inherit map in python?
Or why I can't inherit map in python?

#### add

What I want to achieve is add custom method for iterable object

```
def iter_z(self_obj):
    class IterC(type(self_obj)):
        def __init__(self, self_obj):
            super(iterC, self).__init__(self_obj)
            self.obj = self_obj
        def map(self, func):
            return iter_z(list(map(func, self.obj))) # I want to remove "list" here, but I can't. Otherwise it cause TypeError
        def filter(self, func):
            return iter_z(list(filter(func, self.obj))) # I want to remove "list" here, but I can't. Otherwise it cause TypeError
        def list(self):
            return iter_z(list(self.obj))
        def join(self, Jstr):
            return Jstr.join(self)
return IterC(self_obj)
```

So that I can do this:

```
a = iter_z([1,3,5,7,9,100])
a.map(lambda x:x+65).filter(lambda x:x<=90).map(lambda x:chr(x)).join("")
# BDFHJ
```

Instead of this:

```
"".join(map(lambda x:chr(x),filter(lambda x:x<=90,map(lambda x:x+65,a))))
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. `map` is technically a class in CPython, but this is not a documented guarantee, and either way, that `__init__` doesn't make sense for a `map` subclass.

Comment: Whatever you were trying to achieve, subclassing `map` is almost certainly not the way to achieve it.

Comment: why do you need to subclass map for this??? Also, stop using `list` on all your iterators, that *defeats the point of them being iterators*. Anyway, you can inherit map, but I wouldn't for the reasons stated above. Note, `__new__` is probably getting in the way of your implementations

Comment: Again, what's the point of creating a class for each function call, and dynamically inheriting `class iterC(type(self_obj))`? Why not just a class outside of the function that doesn't inherit from anything (except object by default)?, i.e. `class iterC: ...`?

Comment: Because I want keep all original method of original object. like `[a for a in iterZ(iterable).map(xxx).filter(xxx).reduce(xxx)]`

Comment: This is a job for a wrapper, not a subclass. You're not using any methods of the original object, anyway - the only methods a map iterator has are things you're unlikely to want to call directly.

Comment: @JK-Hu it sounds like you want to define an *iterable*, `map` objects are iterables, indeed, they are iterators, but you shouldn't inherit from `map` to define your own iterable or iterator. This sounds like the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: And fundamentally, you seem to want a fluent, streaming API, something like [Java Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/). You would want to design that from the ground up, don't use inheritance. The built-in types you are trying to utilize are not designed to be used the way you are trying to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be inheriting from the object you're wrapping. That's because your API is different from that type, and there's no good way to ensure you can build a new instance of the class properly. Your `map` situation is an example of this, your `__init__` expects a different number of argumetns than `map.__new__` does, and there's no good way to rationalize them.

Instead of inheriting from the class, just wrap around it. This might limit the API of the type that can be used, but you're mostly focused on the iterator protocol, so probably `__iter__` and `__next__` are all you need:

```
class IterZ:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.iterator)

    def map(self, func):
        return IterZ(map(func, self.iterator))

    def filter(self, func):
        return IterZ(filter(func, self.iterator))

    def join(self, Jstr):
        return Jstr.join(self.iterator)
```

Comment: Yea, your solution works. But I want to build a class that more general so that I can `iterZ([1,2,3])[1]` or `print(iterZ([1,2,3]))` without define `__getitem__ ` and `__str__` etc. , the class can auto retrieve it from parent class.

Comment: @JK-Hu you don't want inheritance here, it is totally the wrong tool. There are more straightforward ways for what you are trying to do, in python, writing some sort of proxy or wrapper is very straightforward. Inheritance is best used sparingly, it forces hierarchical relationships which in the end limit the sort of code re-use you want to accomplish.

Comment: Okay. Just a question, do you know any elegant way to do this? I want make `a==b` `a+b` `a>b` `len(a)` `sorted(a)` etc. works as original object if `a=iterZ([1,3,2])`? Currently I am defined all of the magic methods that these operator needs, but I just want add method to existing class. Except inherit, is there any way to proxy all method and attribute to original object?

Comment: It's hard to be a perfect proxy for all types, but yes, in general you just need to implement the `__dunder__` methods to implement operators and such, and a `__getattribute__` method to look up named methods and attributes (it won't help with operators, as the special methods are looked up directly on the class, not via the instance).